# C++ template aliasing g++ 5.4

Tags: c++11, templates

I'am not able to compile any trivial C++ aliasing declaration.
Here is my dev env :

```
g++ (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.11) 5.4.0 20160609
```

Here is my snippet (file tstFrameProd.cpp):

```
template<typename T = double>
struct mystruct {};

template<typename T = double> using myalias = mystruct<T>;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
      return 0;
}
```

Here is my compilation process :

```
g++  -g -std=c++11  -W -Wall -I../include  -I../../../Toolbox/CShmRingBuf/ -I/opt/matrox_imaging/mil/include -Woverloaded-virtual -ansi -pipe -fno-for-scope -DGNU_GCC  -DDEBUG   -c -o tstFrameProd.o tstFrameProd.cpp
```

Here is my compilation error message :

```
tstFrameProd.cpp:20:31: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘using’
 template<typename T = double> using myalias = mystruct<T>;
```

Comment: no error compiling with g++ 6.3.0

Comment: Not seeing any problem on my desktop using g++ 7.3.0. Please post a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're compiling with `-ansi` which negates the effect of `-std=c++11`. Simply remove it.